# How do I change default font of Summernote in Django?

Tags: django, summernote

So I'm using django-summernote (I'm using Django ver 3.x), and trying to change the default font in the editor. Here's my code.
(part of) forms.py:

```
from .models import MyModel

class MyInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    contents = SummernoteTextFormField()

        class Meta:
        model=MyModel
        fields=['contents']
        widgets = {
        'contents': SummernoteInplaceWidget()
        }
```

(part of) my template :

```
<form method="post" class="form-group">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-8">
      {{form.contents|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And in case you need to take a look, (part of) my settings.py

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'iframe': True,
    'lang' : 'ko-KR',
    'summernote': {
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '400px',
        'toolbar': [
            ['style', ['style',]],
            ['font', ['fontname', 'fontsize', 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'clear',]],
            ['color', ['forecolor', 'backcolor', ]],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'height']],
            ['insert', ['link']],
            ['misc', ['picture', 'fullscreen', 'codeview', 'print', 'help', ]],
        ],
    },
    'js': (
        '/static/summernote-ext-print.js',
    ),
    'js_for_inplace': (
        '/static/summernote-ext-print.js',
    ),
    'css': (
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.40.0/theme/base16-dark.min.css',
    ),
    'css_for_inplace': (
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.40.0/theme/base16-dark.min.css',
    ),
    'codemirror': {
        'theme': 'base16-dark',
        'mode': 'htmlmixed',
        'lineNumbers': 'true',
    },
    'lazy': False,
}

SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

I have no idea on how or where to write my code for changing the default font.
I would really appreciate your help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with django-summernote. You need to check and initialize the default font-family in your css style or html file. Also, you probably need to check what to display in the dropdown, check the [fontNames option](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/c223b08a20c1d8cbe20fb5ba213d617b83c4999f/src/js/base/settings.js#L152)

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'summernote': {
        'fontNames': [...],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding more fonts to the list can be done by:

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'summernote': {
        'fontNames': ['Spectral', 'Quicksand'],
        'fontNamesIgnoreCheck': ['Spectral', 'Quicksand'],
    },
}
```

> Summernote tests for fonts in fontNames before adding them to
> dropdown. This is a problem while using web fonts. It’s not easy
> picking a nice time to check the availability of web fonts. You can
> define a list of web fonts to be ignored with the
> fontNamesIgnoreCheck.

Reference: https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-fontnames

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't worry about that. Copy and paste text in any format in the editor, summernote will accept and adjust.